# Use knockout foreach to generate elements, but keep static elements

Tags: knockout.js

I want to use Knockout to generate the following HTML

```
<tr>
    <th>Substatus</th>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
```

If the data model looks like this...

```
function Model() {
    var self = this;
    self.headers = ko.observableArray([{ Description: 'Header 1' }, { Description: 'Header 2' }]);
}
```

Notice the first and last column header are not specified by the data model, but, rather, are statically defined.  How would I change the following template to output the header like I need it?

```
<script type="text/html" id="vendorReportTemplate">
    <tr>
        <th>Substatus</th>

        <!--somehow i need knockout to generate the dynamic headers here-->

        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Virtual Elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html)

```
<tr>
    <th>Substatus</th>

    <!-- ko foreach: headers -->
    <th data-bind="text: Description"></th>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QrMEy/)